# Laravel 6: Not sending email by smtp in live server

Tags: php, laravel-6

I am trying to send a simple email from my live website. But I am getting an error:

```
smtp connect() failed. error 101
```

**This is my .env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=innovamep.email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secretpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**This is my mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','innovamep.email@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','secretpassword'),
```

**Note:** email has been successfully sent from another hosting. But in the production hosting it is not working. What is going wrong here? Thank You.

Comment: From your server, open the command prompt and run `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. If your connection is successful you can see `Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.`. Otherwise, please check it with the hosting provider whether they blocked SMTP connections on the port 587.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=innovamep.email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secretpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Go to your "Manage your Google Account" and Allow less secure apps: ON as per below screenshots
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ensure your Gmail account is setup correctly for remote sending. it won't be by default.
Specifically look into Gmail's "less secure app" options.